# Debugger does not work in Rake task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, debugging

I'm using ruby 2.1.0 and Rails 4.1.0

If I put a `debugger` statement anywhere in my rake code, I get this:

```
home/vagrant/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/monitor.rb:213
mon_exit

[208, 217] in /home/vagrant/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/monitor.rb
   208    def mon_synchronize
   209      mon_enter
   210      begin
   211        yield
   212      ensure
=> 213        mon_exit
   214      end
   215    end
   216    alias synchronize mon_synchronize
   217
(rdb:1)
```

I cannot access any of the local variables in my code.
Monitor appears to be a threading library... so how do I get the debugger statement to run properly?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was putting "`debugger`" at the end of a method, which would make it the return value.

The fix... don't put `debugger` at the end of a method.